# How do I get device token in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm using expo 35 and trying to use external push notification service. My notification service require device token to register user in their service.

So I tried Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync but it need gcmSenderId so I confused.

Do I have to use Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync to get device token in React Native? or do I have to use other way to get device token?

Thanks in advance.